# Format output of an array map

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates, reduce

I am trying to make a function that counts duplicates, this works but not in the output format I need.
This is my function:

```
    var duplicateCount = {};
    countryArray.forEach(e => duplicateCount[e] = duplicateCount[e] ? duplicateCount[e] + 1 : 
    1);
     result5 = Object.keys(duplicateCount).map(e => {return {key:e, count:duplicateCount[e]}});
    console.log("result5", result5);
```

The output I get is:

```
    result5 
    (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {e: "CRM", count: 6}
    1: {e: "TSA", count: 8}
    2: {e: "PCS", count: 3}
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

The output I need is:

```
    result5 
    (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {"CRM", 6}
    1: {"TSA", 8}
    2: {"PCS", 3}
    length: 3
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

Any help is good. Thank!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean you want the e property to be the key? (it shows a , instead of :)

```js
const data = [
   {e: "CRM", count: 6},
   {e: "TSA", count: 8},
   {e: "PCS", count: 3}
  ]
     

const output1 = data.map(obj => ({[obj.e]:null, [obj.count]:null}))

const output2 = data.map(obj => ({[obj.e]:obj.e, [obj.count]:obj.count}))

const output3 = data.map(obj => ([obj.e, obj.count]))



console.log("output1:",output1, "output2:",output2, "output3:",output3)
```

Comment: Must be comma not colon

Comment: I changed it, but if you leave it as an object it forces the values to be null. I included 2 other versions you may have meant (where key = value, and where array is returned instead of object).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need an array of objects. But {"CRM", 6} is incorrect object syntax. The object should contain key: value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.enties` and `map`

```js
countryArray = ["foo", "bar", "foo"];
var duplicateCount = {};

countryArray.forEach((e) => (duplicateCount[e] = (duplicateCount[e] ?? 0) + 1));

result5 = Object.entries(duplicateCount).map(([key, value]) => ({
  [key]: value,
}));

console.log("result5", result5);
```